# Studio Ghibli HTTP Requests

Tags: python, json, api

First time doing this. When I run this code it doesn't let me input `name` and gives an error.

```
import requests
print('Studio Ghibli -' + 'это японская студия анимационных фильмов, соучредителями которой являются: \n Исао Такахата, Хаяо Миядзаки, Тошио Сузуки и Ясуёси Токума.\n'
                     ' Компания начала свою деятельность в июне 1985 года в качестве дочернего предприятия Tokuma Shoten Co., Ltd.\n'
                     'Все названия аниме от Studio Ghibli - https://yaokino.ru/multfilmy-studii-ghibli-spisok')
BASE_URL = "http://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com"
main_data = requests.get(BASE_URL).json()
name = input("\nНапишите название аниме и мы дадим информацию о ней: ")
```

But I think this why

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\122\Desktop\2\5\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\122\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\122\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\122\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\122\Desktop\2\5\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    main_data = requests.get(BASE_URL).json()
  File "C:\Users\122\Desktop\2\5\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I write `.json()`, it gives me another error. How to fix it?

Comment: Please give the whole traceback, thanks!

Comment: @FelixKleineBösing, okay, done!

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to read into API's. You use a base URL which contains HTML on how to use their API (just browse to the url and see). This will not translate into JSON. Instead use one of their API's to retrieve JSON. They provide the OpenAPI spec with all the resources at the top of the page. Read that and try accessing one of the resources.